# Checking for the presence of posts in a category does not work. php, Blade, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade, laravel-relations

I have a view with all categories, by clicking on a category, the user can go to that category. But I want to prevent going there if there are no posts in that category. I tried to do this:

```
@if(($category->id === $category->posts()) !== 0)
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('category', $category->code)}}">Open</a>
@else
   <span class="btn btn-warning">No posts in this category</span>
@endif
```

`posts()` is an eloquent relationship in my Category model:

```
public function posts() {
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

But it doesn't work. All categories are written either "The post has no categories" or "Open". That is, the check does not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your blade file check condition like that

```
@if($category->posts_count > 0)
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('category', $category->code)}}">Open</a>
@else
   <span class="btn btn-warning">No posts in this category</span>
@endif
```

**in your controller used [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method**

```
$category = Category::withCount('posts')->get();
```

and in your category model add relationship if not added[(one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many))

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in controller you can do

```php
$category = Category::withCount('posts')->get()
```

it generate `post_count` key which you can check in view

```php
@if($category->posts_count > 0)
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('category', $category->code)}}">Open</a>
@else
   <span class="btn btn-warning">No posts in this category</span>
@endif
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

---

Update

```php
$category = Category::withCount('posts')->findOrFail(1)

if($category->posts_count > 1){
   return redirect()->back() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how can you prevent the transition? Now navigates to the page, even if it is empty.

Comment: ohh then you need `withCount()`

Comment: I am very sorry, but how can I do the same check in the controller? I want to `return redirect()->back()` if the number of posts is less than 1.

Comment: @Hi_TecH check i added that

Comment: `Trying to get property 'posts_count' of non-object`. I assume this is due to the value of find().

Comment: use `findOrFail()` then

Comment: What does '1' means in a find function?

Comment: $categoryId it is